# What is the difference between .dex and .apk file?

Tags: applications, kernel

.dex and .apk file: What are they and how do they execute ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_application_package and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_(software). APKs hold the app, while DEX's are only exported executable's. An APK may contain a `classes.dex` to be executed but this can be ignored if a proper exported `*.dex` or `*.odex` file is present.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, an APK file is a ZIP file, where you can found the Magic Number `PK` in the file header. It contains not only `classes.dex` but also other meta files such as `AndroidManifest.xml` which contains the basic configuration of this file.

A .dex file is just... uh, I regard it as a "real" executable, like an .exe file in Windows or an ELF in Linux, which contains the machine code(for Dalvik VM).

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between .dex and .apk file?

.dex file
Compiled Android application code file.

Android programs are compiled into .dex (Dalvik Executable) files, which are in turn zipped into a single .apk file on the device. .dex files can be created by automatically by Android translating compiled applications written in the Java programming language.

Reference: [Answer by Vineet Shukla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7750464)

Comment: That's.. not how you refer to another post on SE. You should quote the relevant part, and give the link as the reference, *not* posting the link only.

Comment: Okay. Didn't know that. Will keep in mind the next time.